# pass limit to "in" query in mysql

Tags: mysql

My table is like:
[image]

now here I want to pass limit for particular voices_id.

I mean if I want just 3 records of particular voices_id then how to do so? (3 records for voices_id=153 & 154) where to pass limit ?

Comment: Probably doing `union all`

Comment: can you show me any example please?

Comment: oh I dont want to use union, is there any other option?

Comment: So you want 3 record per group and its only for voices_id 153 and 154 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do

```
select *
from table_name t1
where t1.voices_id in (153,154)
and
(
   select count(*) from table_name t2
   where t1.voices_id = t2.voices_id and t1.id <= t2.id
) <= 3
order by t1.voices_id
;
```

Here the condition `t1.id <= t2.id` will give you last 3 entry per group, you can reverse it for first 3 entry.

Comment: do you have any idea of yii? I want above query for yii2

Comment: I am really sorry I don't know yii

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as this:

```
SELECT * FROM voices_talks WHERE voices_id=153 LIMIT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM voices_talks WHERE voices_id=154 LIMIT 3
```